# implement Sliding Window to detect text in an image

Tags: machine-learning, python

I am working on a text detection in the images. How can I implement a sliding window in a python to detect text in an image?

Comment: Sliding windows is not a machine learning technique to detect text. Doing it this way would require too much unnecessary processing.There are [other ways of doing it](http://www.citeulike.org/user/mapto/tag/text_detection). Because of this, I suggest this question is moved to another StackExchange community, either StackOverflow or one about graphics.

Comment: Take a look at the video which is provided [here](http://yosinski.com/deepvis).